# PHP DomElement: See if element is a direct or indirect child of another element

Tags: php, xml

Let's say I have the following XML:

```
<family>
    <father>
        <date_of_birth>1971-01-25</date_of_birth>
        <first_name>Bob</first_name>
        <last_name>Johnson</last_name>
    </father>
    <mother>
        <date_of_birth>1977-09-12</date_of_birth>
        <first_name>Mary</first_name>
        <last_name>Johnson</last_name>
    </mother>
    <child>
        <date_of_birth>2006-04-21</date_of_birth>
        <first_name>Pete</first_name>
        <last_name>Johnson</last_name>
    </child>
</family>
```

And I decide I want to use only `<date_of_birth>` values. I do the following:

```
$DOBs = $dom->getElementsByTagName("date_of_birth");
```

Now, my question is, while I'm looping through the values:

```
foreach ($DOBs as $date)
{
    echo $date->nodeValue . "<br>";
}
```

How can I tell if these values came from a mother, father or child? Is there a way to check and see if the `DomElement` $date is a child or grandchild of mother or father? Basically I need to know if any of these are within a  tag (no matter how deep).

**EDIT**

For example (please note that the method `is_child_of` is made up):

```
foreach ($DOBs as $date)
{
    if($date->is_child_of('father'))
    {
        //This is the father's date of birth.
    }
}
```

I'm looking for something that tells me this `<date_of_birth>` is inside another element. So if I say:

```
if($date->is_child_of('family'))
{

}
```

or

```
if($date->is_child_of('father'))
{

}
```

these would both be true (assuming we're dealing with the father's date_of_birth) and the code inside the if statements will fire.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only looking for direct parent, use the `parentNode` and `nodeName` attribute of the `DOMNode` instance.

For indirect parent, other than using XPath, the only thing I know is this function:

```
function isChildOf(DOMNode $childNode, $parentNodeName)
{
    while ($childNode->parentNode)
    {
        if ($childNode->parentNode->nodeName == $parentNodeName) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            $childNode = $childNode->parentNode;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Untested**, use at your own risk.